# Replace starting and ending tag based on class name

Tags: javascript, string

I want to replace starting and ending tag using **javascript only**

```
<span> Hello john</span><div class="replace-class"> John likes to play guitar</div><div>Anna likes to arrange flowers</div>
```

in above example div tag with class="replace-class" should be replaced with tag

. As below

```
<span> Hello john</span><p> John likes to play guitar</p><div>Anna likes to arrange flowers</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: @Luca I understand you point, but this is only explanation I have. I tried to search it but did not got any answer and I am not that much familiar with regex. Still let me know if you need any extra detail, I will provide you. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Select the `outerHTML` of the element with class `replace-class`
2. Then if your browser supports `outerHTML` it is easy to replace the element (as in `if` block)
3. But if your browser do not supports `outerHTML` then you need to select the parent element also so that you can take it as a base and replace the element with `replace-class` class.

```js
var Obj = document.querySelector('.replace-class'); 
var str = '<p>' + Obj.innerHTML + '</p>';
if(Obj.outerHTML) { 
    Obj.outerHTML=str;
}
else { 
  var tmpObj=document.createElement("p");
  tmpObj.innerHTML= Obj.innerHTML;
  ObjParent=Obj.parentNode;
  ObjParent.replaceChild(tmpObj,Obj);
}
```

```html
<span> Hello john</span><div class="replace-class"> John likes to play guitar</div><div>Anna likes to arrange flowers</div>
```

for further verification of the snippet you can use `inspect element` of the browser and check the element. The `div` should have been replaced with 
    `p`